# How to search query in all collections in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'va 6 collections in my mongodb database. let say 6 collections name is 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', and 'F'. All those collections have title field. I wanna search text in all collections into title field. My code is:

```
router.get("/home", async (req, res) => {
   if (req.query.search) {
      let result = [];
      const collections = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
      const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');

      for (let collection of collections) {
         let group = mongoose.model(collection);
         result.push(...await group.find({ 'title': regex }));
      }
      res.render("public/hadith.ejs", { search: result});
   }
});

function escapeRegex(text) {
   return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

I'm using regular expression to modify search text. That works for me. Can anyone please tell me is that good or bad way or something better then this.

Answer (score 0):

First in nodejs and mongodb always avoid these kind of condition where you have to merge data of multiple collection because it impact the performance and defeat the purpose of mongodb.
Meanwhile there is $lookup operator for join operation but try to avoid it in frequent queries.
About this question to do query for each collection is better then join. So i think performance wise its good, just remember to do indexing(text indexes) of keys ("title") in each collection and use wildcard smartly.
And in the above condition if title is not in collection it will insert empty value in array, correct it.